# Chrome tab hanging on documentation page for minutes

Tags: bug, documentation

This question https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/24/c-sharp-6-0-features is causing my chrome tab to hang. The page renders, but I can't scroll or do anything on the page. The loading spinner just kept going for a few minutes before it finally started becoming responsive.

It loads most of the page, but says it's still loading. I couldn't find anything in the F12 developer tools that looked like it could be the cause. No failing requests, no outstanding requests in the network tab.

Each chrome.exe in my task manager with this tab open is using 13% of my CPU and accumulating a lot of memory.

I noticed that when it finally loaded, it was currently being edited by 5 people, that might be a factor.

The page loaded fine in Firefox until I logged in. Then I got an unresponsive script message from a script `docs-transpiled.en.js`

Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: No problems on IE 11.

Comment: I've had I cpu usage on firefox. consistent ~10%. There's also some sluggishness.  Not a fan of the live markdown editor